# What does the following error message mean in FreeDOS?

Tags: drivers, optical-drive, freedos

I'm in the process of installing the newest version of my BIOS driver and I have to use FreeDOS because I don't have windows (I'm using Ubuntu 9.10). So I'm following AndrejaKo's advice [here](https://superuser.com/questions/170624/how-do-i-install-a-new-bios-driver-on-ubuntu-9-10-karmic-koala). The problem is that when FreeDOS comes up and I choose option #5: FreeDOS Live CD only, I don't end up with the same screen as AndrejaKo's. Rather, I get this:

```
UMB's unavailable!
XCDROM V2.3, 7-24-2006.
Driver name is "FDCD0000".
No CD-ROM drive to use; XCDROM not loaded!
FreeCom version 0.84-pre2 XMS_Swap [Aug282006 00:29:00]
Cannot open CD driver FDCD0000. SHCDX33A cannot load!
There is no CDROM, or the wrong CD-ROM!

A:/>
```

Does anyone know what this means? It seems to indicate that there is a problem with my CD driver, but I do get that far in FreeDOS from a live CD.. AND other CD work fine on my machine... So what's the deal?

edit: In System->Administration->Disk Utility, Under CD/DVD Drive, I get this:

> Optiarc DVD RW AD-75805 No Media
>   Detected

If I start hardinfo and go in Computer>Summary, I find a section called SCSI Disks with this entry:

> Optiarc DVD RW AD-7580S

I don't know if this can be useful.

By the way, my computer is an Acer Aspire 5536-5519

Comment: How is the CD drive connected to the PC - which interface?

Comment: @Moritz Both: I don't know how to get that information... There must be a simple command which could find that for me?

Comment: @Moritz Both: I edited my thread with some information, I don't know if this is what you're looking for..

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using a sata-connected DVD drive (Macbook?).

I think the XCDROM driver is for IDE devices only. There are other drivers in FreeDOS that work with SATA DVDs ([GCDROM](http://www.freedos.org/software/?prog=gcdrom)) so perhaps a different menu option or setting from the live CD menu will load them.

If there is no such option you can add gcdrom to the config yourself, follow the instructions [here](http://www.z80.eu/freedoscd.html).

Comment: Hi! Do you know any option which will not load himem or emm386?

Comment: @AndrejaKo Why? Are these undesirable for some reason? Should I give those options a try anyways?
@Console By the way, I don't have a Macbook, I have an Acer Aspire 5536-5519

Comment: @Shawn Well phlash16 refused to work when I booted DOS with himem and emm386 and said that I need to run it without them, so yes they are undesirable.

Comment: @Shawn Actually, do try those options. Nothing bad will happen if you do and if they do work, there may be a way to unload emm386 and himem after boot.

Comment: @AndrejaKo @Console I tried both Himem and emm386 and himem only options. They both produce the same error, with additionnal stuff concerning himem.. Basically, they don't help. I also tried running FreeDOS from a live USB key, but when I choose Default, it just says bad kernel image or something like that, so I never even got to the freeDOS menu that way.

Comment: Himem and emm386 are not undesirable in themselves, they are used to enable memory over the 640k conventional memory in DOS. In fact, the drivers you are trying to load for the DVD drive might even require you to have himem and emm386 loaded. 

I updated the answer with a link to a site that explains how to make a FreeDOS iso that loads gcdrom instead of xcdrom, I think that will solve your problem.

Comment: @Console If it's easy to modify FreeDOS iso, maybe we can skip this whole prblem with CD-ROM drivers? He just needs to add a single directory to iso which will contain the flash program and image. Any links for that?

Comment: My overheating problem is making windows 7 useless in my virtual machine and I found out there is a broken pin in the cable for my desktop's screen making it useless (it had xp). I tried following the instructions with linux iso editor isoMaster but when I get to the "Expand the file fdboot.img.gz with an windows archiver or with gzip" step, I can't expand it (I tried gunzip, tar and zcat). I was wondering if one of you didn't mind helping me out on this one. I mean, in theory, you could modify the iso and send it over right? I wouldn't usually ask this, sorry.

Comment: @Console @AndrejaKo *gunzip* and *zcat* both say "gzip: fdboot.img.gz: not in gzip format" but *tar -xvzf fdboot.img.gz* says "gzip: stdin: not in gzip format". I presume there must be something wrong with the my call; it seems to read from stdin rather than from the file I passed as an argument. Can't figure it out.

Comment: @Console @AndrejaKo Ok I finally got XP to work and modified the ISO. Now, when I choose option #6 FreeDOS Live CD with SATA-CD driver, I get this:
"UMB's unavailable!
GCDROM V2.4, 2-6-2007
Driver name is "FDCD0000".
No CD-ROM drive to use; GCDROM not loaded!
FreeCom version 0.84-pre2 XMS_Swap [Aug 28 2006 00:29:00]
Current date is Tue 08-17-2010
Enter new date (mm-dd[cc]yy):
Current time is 12:38:35.93 am
Enter new time:
A:/>
And if I try typing "X:" it says "Invalid drive X:."
What does this mean

Comment: UMB = upper memory blocks. Without going to a huge amount of details about how DOS handles memory, the error message means you need to load himem. If option 6 is the one that skips himem and emm386, the easiest way for you is probably to add gcdrom to one of the earlier menu options. Keep in mind that Himem must be loaded before gcdrom in the config file.

(It is also possible you can get it to work if you load gcdrom with DEVICE= instead of DEVICEHIGH=, but I'd recommend using the himem option)

Comment: @Console Still not working, I replaced this line: "345?!DEVICEHIGH=A:\DRIVER\XCDROM.SYS /D:FDCD0000" with this one "345?!DEVICEHIGH=A:\DRIVER\GCDROM.SYS /D:FDCD0000" to make sure I have GCDROM instead of XCDROM with every option. Option himem and emm386 says EDD BIOS error! Unit ignored and eventually the same old GCDROM ... Driver name... No CD-ROM drive to use; GCDROM not loaded! ..........Cannot open client CD-ROM device driver FDCD0000 CDRcache will not stay resident.
Cannot open CD driver CDRCACH0. SHCDX33A cannot load!
THere is no CDROM, or the wrong CD-ROM!

Comment: Himem option does the same, but add's in the UMB's unavailable! error

Comment: The EDD Bios error seems to be a catch22 for you, read about it here: http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/micro/pc-stuff/freedos/files/dos/udma/devel/udma2_19.txt.

I suggest you look into booting freeDOS from a USB memory stick or something instead of a CD-ROM, if you google a bit you will find good resources. (I am not a FreeDOS expert, I'm just old enough to know how DOS works :))

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, try checking your BIOS to see if there is an option to switch to ATA compatibility mode.